# Testing a Fragment's onCreate method with a savedInstanceState Bundle in Robolectric?

Tags: android, testing, android-fragments, robolectric

I have a Fragment with an onCreate method that does some stuff with the passed in savedInstanceState Bundle. I'm using Robolectric to create an Activity and starting the Fragment with the Activity's FragmentManager.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to insert a savedInstanceState Bundle from the test code to validate the code path that uses it.

I was hoping that Robolectric had a shadow Fragment that would let me set the bundle directly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Robolectric version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Robolectric 2.x then you can pass `Bundle` to activity:

```
Bundle savedBundle = new Bundle();

activity = buildActivity( FragmentActivity.class ).create( savedBundle ).start().resume().get();

MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add( fragment, null );
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: This just doesn't work for me. I pass in a bundle but when onCreate is called on my fragment, the savedInstanceState Bundle is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using reflection and setting package-private field `mSavedFragmentState` to the Bundle I wanted to receive.

```
    Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    Field field = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mSavedFragmentState");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(fragment, bundle);

    SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment);
```